# Pass DataFrame to parse() in spider class

Tags: pandas, scrapy, web-crawler

Im making a database with products of an eShop, i want to save all the data as a JSON file.
I was wondering a way to pass values of the dataframe used to list the links the spider crawl

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd

class subcategoryExtractorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'subcategorySpider'
    
    # page to scrape

    targets = pd.read_json('categories.json')
    start_urls = targets["link"].values.tolist()

    def parse(self, response):

        #
        subcategories = response.css('div.list-content.j_option_list.j_category_type')
        for subcategory in subcategories.css('a'):
            yield {
            #'category' : category name
            'subcategory': subcategory.css('a::text').get(),
            'link': subcategory.css('a').attrib['href']
            }
```

as you can see i commented 'category' in the yield, i'll like to output the category of the link i'm crawling witch is in targets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you need to pass categories from Pandas through to your final output?

Scrapy has this : [cb_kwargs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions) which allows you to pass values

see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-zX4xQUzT8